# django tenant random domain_url and schema_name

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I came accross a problem with django tenant. 
I created a random schema_name and domain_url on my create function like such:

```
new_key = random_id()
request.data['schema_name'] = new_key
request.data['domain_url'] = new_key

def random_id(size=16, chars=string.ascii_uppercase):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

When I execute this code I get an Unable to create the django_migrations table (relation "django_migrations" already exists) But this only happens why I try to use this random_id function, if I set a static value I have no problem at all. I think this might be a timing issue. Any thoughts?
thanks

```
=== Running migrate for schema CNMHJLELEIQPUSPI
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: clients, oauth2_provider, locale, payables, auth, receivables, accounting, coop, guardian, users, contenttypes, budget
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Internal Server Error: /clients/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_migrations" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 284, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_migrations" already exists


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 87, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/griffin/workspace/myapp/superapp/superapp/clients/views.py", line 159, in create
    user_validated_data=user_serializer.validated_data
  File "/home/griffin/workspace/myapp/superapp/superapp/clients/serializers.py", line 40, in create
    on_trial=validated_data['on_trial']
  File "/home/griffin/workspace/myapp/superapp/superapp/clients/models.py", line 24, in create
    new_client.save()
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tenant_schemas/models.py", line 52, in save
    self.create_schema(check_if_exists=True, verbosity=verbosity)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tenant_schemas/models.py", line 99, in create_schema
    verbosity=verbosity)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 119, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tenant_schemas/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 39, in handle
    self.run_migrations(self.schema_name, settings.TENANT_APPS)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tenant_schemas/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 50, in run_migrations
    command.execute(*self.args, **self.options)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 204, in apply_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 72, in record_applied
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/griffin/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (relation "django_migrations" already exists
```

It is an API, I actually send a post request with the information and create the domain_url and schema_name with the function random_id. This only happens when I use the function, not when I specify that information as a string.

Comment: execute this code? how? Please post the full error trace

Comment: execute the code when I hit an end point.

Comment: I also facing the the same problem. @EnixSys have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, postgres will turn every uppercase schema name into lowercase

```
CREATE SCHEMA Km9GDUY1L9vKexXd;

\dn

      List of schemas
       Name       | Owner  
------------------+--------
 first            | mo
 km9gduy1l9vkexxd | mo
 myschema         | mo
 public           | mo
```

Since we are creating schemas from python code, change ascii_uppercase to ascii_lowercase

```
def random_id(size=16, chars=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```